# Create angular module that includes ngrx strore

Tags: angular, npm, ngrx

I have a question. How can I create angular module that uses ngrx and own store and pack it in npm package for use in another angular app?
For example I have an `app1` it uses own ngrx store and services and components. And in this `app1` I need to include module (another mini app) than has own store and services and own components? Is is possible? I mean how the two stores will be merged? And will I be able to use services from the packed module?
Hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer this with few articles and resources, This can be achieved through Lazy Loading the modules, that encapsulated the Components, Services and Store.

[Lazy Loading Modules](https://medium.com/@AnkurRatra/lazy-loading-of-modules-with-ngrx-store-4th-version-angular-2-23c93295d4e8)

[You Tube Lazy Loading](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Bv5zJY2jAE)

[My github repo for simple example](https://github.com/hamzazaidi/angular-7/tree/002-ngrx-with-lazy-loaded-feature)

There are plenty of resources available.

Comment: Thanks man, it helped me a lot. Lazy loaded store is cool feature. Now I few things left.

Comment: leave a comment if you have anything in specific.

Comment: I need to know how to pack my module into the npm package to reuse it in defferent projects

Comment: You can create a module as angular library, angular cli can generate a library that can be bundled and packaged as npm and you can use is in multiple projects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible, you might want to register the module's reducers using `asFeature`, then you would be able to access it in `app1` just as you would any other feature state.